# How to use rename() and rename_with() under the same dataset in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, rename

```
A data.frame: 6 × 3
Id  ActivityDay Calories
<dbl>   <chr>   <int>
1   1503960366  4/12/2016   1985
2   1503960366  4/13/2016   1797
3   1503960366  4/14/2016   1776
4   1503960366  4/15/2016   1745
5   1503960366  4/16/2016   1863
6   1503960366  4/17/2016   1728
```

Above is a `head()` preview of the dataset, I am trying to convert column name **ActivityDay** into **ActivityDate** while converting all the column names into lower cases, following are my codes:

```
# calories
calories %>%
    rename_with(calories, tolower) %>%
    rename(activitydate=activityday)
Error: Can't rename columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `ActivityDay` doesn't exist.
```

Please help point out where I did wrong with the codes, thank you!

Comment: Next time use `dput(calories)` to prepare a sample of your dataset that can be easily used by the answerers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to call `calories` (your dataframe name) twice:

```r
calories %>% 
  rename_with(tolower) %>% 
  rename(activitydate = activityday)
```

---

data

```r
calories <- structure(list(Id = c(1503960366L, 1503960366L, 1503960366L, 
1503960366L, 1503960366L, 1503960366L), ActivityDay = c("4/12/2016", 
"4/13/2016", "4/14/2016", "4/15/2016", "4/16/2016", "4/17/2016"
), Calories = c(1985L, 1797L, 1776L, 1745L, 1863L, 1728L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I removed the duplicate data frame name and it worked. Also, I want to thank you for helping edit the table, haven't figured out how to list a table yet, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

calories %>% 
  rename_with(., ~tolower(str_replace(., "activityday", "activitydate"))))
```

```
          id activitydate calories
1 1503960366    4/12/2016     1985
2 1503960366    4/13/2016     1797
3 1503960366    4/14/2016     1776
4 1503960366    4/15/2016     1745
5 1503960366    4/16/2016     1863
6 1503960366    4/17/2016     1728
```